# Intellij reports code duplication while actually it's not

Tags: intellij-idea

Here's the code. The code in method test and test2 are different because the parameter passed to Test constructor are different. Actually, if I change any parameter to null, intellij stops reporting the duplication. Is there any way to fix this?

---- Updated --------

I pass 2 functions doing totally different things but intellij still reports duplication

```
public class TestMain {

    public void test(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("haha");
        System.out.println("hahaa");
        TestMain testMain = new TestMain();
        new Test(testMain::test3);
        System.out.println("hahaaa");
    }

    public void test2(int a)
    {
        System.out.println("haha");
        System.out.println("hahaa");
        TestMain testMain = new TestMain();
        new Test(testMain::still_dup);
        System.out.println("hahaaa");
    }

    public void test3(int a) {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }

    public void still_dup(int a) {
        String b = "edf";
        b.toLowerCase();
    }

    public class Test {
        Test(handler h) {

        }
    }

    public interface handler<M> {
        void entitySelector(int a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMain test = new TestMain();
        test.test(1);
        System.out.println("-------");
        test.test2(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You pass two different methods references, but the two referenced methods do the exact same thing.

Comment: @JBNizet it's not the point. Even though I pass a function doing a totally different thing, it also reports duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to fix this is to replace `test` and `test2` by a single method. You don't have to distinguish what to pass the constructor because it's the current method. This might be the reason why code duplication is reported. The methods can be replaced by a single one without problems.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a single method'?

Comment: What I mean is to replace both methods by one method.

Comment: The answer does not apply any more because the question was updated. The method references that are passed in test and test2 are changed.